# Vector get only no repeating elements

Tags: c++

I want to write a function which will return amount of no repeating digits. So far I have written a function which is iterating through char and collecting to vector all number, but the problem comes when I have to get from vector only non repeating digits. 

My code:

```
int norepeat(char *word){
    int i = 0;
    int size = 0;
    vector<int> tab;
    while (word[i] != '\0'){
        if (word[i] >= '0' && word[i] <= '9') {
            int num = word[i];
            tab.push_back(num);
            sort(tab.begin(),tab.end());
            unique(tab.begin(),tab.end());
            size = tab.size();
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return size;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Several examples how should it work:

```
norepeat("de32ge2sa3ds1") => 1
norepeat("defegtdsg") => 0
norepeat("12341234") => 0
norepeat("1yle2le49") => 4
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you only want the digits that appear exactly once in the string? Then your `std::unique` should work; but do it after the while loop.

Comment: @haavee exactly as you said. I have already moved it outside the loop but it still not working

Comment: Because I was wrong :-) `std::unique` does not what you want by default.

Comment: You don't want unique elements, you want the ones that are not repeated. I think everyone here misunderstood except R Sahu.

Comment: @user4581301 you are right, I know it's not common example but I have tried to describe it clearly. I will edit post with several examples how it should work.

Comment: @Gregy your question was very clear; I understood it 53 minutes ago :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a map of digits -> digit count.

Then iterate through the map and count the number of digits that have a count of 1.

```
int norepeat(char *word){
   int i = 0;
   std::map<char, int> m;
   while (word[i] != '\0'){
      if ( isdigit(word[i] )
         m[word[i]]++;
      ++i;
   }

   int count = 0;
   for ( auto& p : m )
   {
      if ( p.second == 1 )
         ++count;
   }

   return count;
}
```

When working with a compiler that does not support C++11, the `for` loop can be changed to:

```
   std::map<char, int>::iterator iter = m.begin();
   std::map<char, int>::iterator end = m.end();
   for ( ; iter != end; ++iter )
   {
      if ( iter->second == 1 )
         ++count;
   }
```

Comment: can you explain part with `for` loop? beacuse I don't understand it at all

Comment: @Gregy, that is the syntax of the range-for loop that was introduced in C++11. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Nice thing of C++ is the ability to mix Plain-Old-Data pointers and libc functions and algorithms from the C++ standard template library: (note: uses some C++11 features)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

size_t norepeat(const char* word) {
    vector<char>            digits;
    vector<char>::iterator  uniq;

    // Filter the digits
    copy_if(word, word+strlen(word), back_inserter(digits), ::isdigit);

    // get the unique ones
    sort(digits.begin(), digits.end());
    uniq = unique(digits.begin(), digits.end());

    // return amount
    size_t uniques    = std::distance(digits.begin(), uniq);
    size_t duplicates = std::distance(uniq, digits.end());
    return uniques - duplicates;
}

int main( void ) {
    cout << norepeat("hello 123 world 124") << endl;
    cout << norepeat("hello world") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
2
0
```

**EDIT**

Just for laughs: wrote a counting-output-iterator-class; it counts occurrences of values copied into it into a map of `value` -> `unsigned int`. Combined with the `count_if` algorithm (with C++ lambdas) the `norepeat` function itself is only three statements: a variable declaration, filtering the digits and return the result of the counting:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct counter : public iterator<output_iterator_tag, T> {
    typedef map<T, unsigned int> counter_type;

    counter(counter_type* ptr) : mapptr( ptr ) {}

    // decorate with dereference and assignment
    counter<T>& operator=( const T& t ) {
        mapptr->operator[]( t )++;
        return *this;
    }
    counter<T>& operator++() { return *this; }
    counter<T>& operator*() { return *this; }

    counter_type*   mapptr;
};

size_t norepeat(const char* word) {
    typename counter<char>::counter_type countert;

    // Filter the digits
    copy_if(word, word+strlen(word), counter<char>(&countert), ::isdigit);

    // Count the ones that have a value of one
    return count_if(countert.begin(), countert.end(),
                    [](const counter<char>::counter_type::value_type& kv) {
                          return kv.second==1; } );
}

int main( void ) {
    cout << norepeat("hello 123 world 124") << endl; 
    cout << norepeat("hello world") << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recommending one readability tweak right at the end: `uniques = std::distance(digits.begin(), uniq);<EOL>duplicates = std::distance(uniq, digits.end());<EOL>return uniques - duplicates;` Makes the intent of `return (uniq - digits.begin()) - (digits.end() - uniq);` stand out.

Answer (score 1):

Since my last answer was based on a misreading of the question, How about this?

```
int norepeat(const char *word){
    int i = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int arr[10] = {0}; // there are only 10 unique possibilities,
                       // so we'll mark them when found
    while (word[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (std::isdigit(word[i])) 
        {
            int num = word[i] - '0'; // get numeric value of digit to use as index
            arr[num]++; // count the number of times we've seen this digit
        }
        ++i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == 1) // count all element seen only once
        {
            size++;
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

This gag is really limited because it will only work for decimal digits, but with a slight modification it could do upper or lower case characters. With a [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)... The possibilities are limitless! I'll add that for completeness in a second.

## EDIT

The map version.

```
int norepeat(const char *word){
    int i = 0;
    int size = 0;
    std::map<char, int> counts; 
                            
    while (word[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (std::isdigit(word[i])) // could use any or no filtering logic here
        {
            counts[word[i]]++;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    for (auto &count: counts)
    {
        if (count.second == 1) // count all element seen only once
        {
            size++;
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Better; it solves the problem! But it's very C and not C++ at all ;-) The only c++ I see in there is 5 characters long: `std::` ...

Comment: @haavee Weren't you the person just saying one of the beauties of C++ is the ability to drop into the gutter when required?

Comment: Most definitely! But that meant using C++ algorithms on C-style pointers and using 'raw' function pointers (like `::isdigit`) as predicates for those algorithms. That means no overhead at all in writing or constructing wrapper objects or functors; i.e. no actual runtime overhead but all the type safety and known-good behaviour of the algorithms!

Comment: @haavee Big fan of `<algorithm>`, but I couldn't get my set_intersection solution cleaner than a raw array and dumb loops.

Comment: It was all I could do to restrain myself from writing a counting output iterator :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
int norepeat(char *word){

int i = 0;
int size = 0;
vector<int> tab;
while (word[i] != '\0'){
    if (word[i] >= '0' && word[i] <= '9') {
        int num = word[i];
        tab.push_back(num);
    }
    ++i;
}

size = std::distance( unique(tab.begin(),tab.end()), tab.end() );
return size;
```

}

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, I've checked it with `de32ge2sa3ds1` example and it returns `4` instead of `1`

Comment: Oops!  Counted distance wrong way around.  Fixed now.

Comment: i have tried with `1yle2le49` example and it still doesn't work